# Forward mails received to SES to Gmail

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a rule for receiving mail to `info@example.com`, which stores the emails in an S3 bucket. Is it possible to forward them to a Gmail account as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is **no out-of-the-box option** for forwarding emails received by Amazon SES.

You could write an [SES Lambda Action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/receiving-email-action-lambda.html) to do anything (including forwarding emails) but you will need to write and maintain that code.